# Main differences between intuitionistic type theory and calculus of constructions (CoC)

Tags: type-theory, coq

Quoting Wikipedia "Many systems of type theory, such as the simply-typed lambda calculus, intuitionistic type theory, and the calculus of constructions, are also programming languages." I'm a Coq user and, to some extent, familiar with CoC. How CoC differs from intuitionistic type theory (Martin-Löf type theory?) and what are the major consequences of it? Both for proving theorems and for programming.

Comment: This seems to be very similar to the [following question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7561/whats-the-relation-and-difference-between-calculus-of-inductive-constructions-a/30662#30662) on cstheory.